# jquery .each() losing $(this) values

Tags: jquery, width, positioning, each

my margin value is getting set to zero here and i don't see why.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img.thumbNormal').each(function(){
    $(this).css({'position':'relative', 'left':'50%', 'margin-left':-$(this).width()/2});
  });
});
```

if i run the same line in the console, the results are what you'd expect.

any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Is there any other code or a style sheet that might be interfering?

Comment: I think you can even leave out .each, because `$('img.thumbNormal').css(bla)` would already solve that.

Comment: The code looks fine to me and works fine here (http://jsfiddle.net/Wkseg/) likely you have other code/css conflicting.

Comment: I will try putting a parenthesis aroung $(this).width(). I guess you tried debugging using firebug. I will introduce a variable and debug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it after the images have loaded.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('img.thumbNormal').each(function(){
        $(this).css({'position':'relative', 'left':'50%', 'margin-left':-$(this).width()/2});
    });
});
```

You're currently doing it on `$(document).ready()`, which does not wait for the images to load, and the `.width()` of images is `0` until they're fully loaded.